# Angular 2, http post not working

Tags: c#, angular, http, post, asp.net-core-mvc

I am working on Angular 2 ASP.NET Core MVC project.
My Client script calling server side controller

```
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    var url = "MyController/MyAction/";

    var t = this.http.post(url, JSON.stringify(formData), options);
```

the MVC server side controller has following Action

```
    public IActionResult MyAction([FromBody] myViewModel viewModel)
```

it was working fine, the client side was sending client view model, the server was receiving that view model and properly matching it to the server side model

at some point i had to attach jquery package along with jquery.ui and it broke the beauty.

the client side still calling the server and the server is accepting the call properly in the Action. Unfortunately it stoped mapping the view model properly. The action receives null instead of the view model object

any ideas?

Comment: First, test the webservice in postman app, if that works, look at the network call, what is the error? Normally need to have domain/<whatever>/blah.

Comment: Did you tried without `JSON.stringify`?

Comment: A just removed the JSON.stringify and double checked it.
it seems to be passing properly view model till one of the properties (Date holder) gets changed with something like "25/08/2017", and it seems to be causing view model parser to crash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i figured my issue here...

The Client side doesn't really require any JSON.stringify. 
On the top of it, I missed the subscribe part of the call which actually triggers the client to send server request.

```
   getMyServerSideData(form: MyForm) {

    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    var url = "Report/GetMyServerData/";

    return this.http.post(url, form, options)
           .map(response => {
            return response.json() as MyForm;
        })
        .subscribe(data=>{
             console.write(data);
        });
}
```

plus MVC 5 Server side Action call doesn't need [FromBody] tag in front of the parameters

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetCOFData(MyFormServerSideViewModel  viewModel)
    {
      ...
      ...
      ...
          viewModel.prop1 = "aaa",
          viewModel.prop2 = "bbb"


          return Json(response, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```